# Transposing a difficult matrix in Groovy

Tags: algorithm, collections, groovy

How to transpose

```
u2:[g2,g3], u3:[g1,g2,g3], u1:[g1,g2]
```

into

```
g1:[u1,u3], g2:[u1,u2,u3], g3:[u2,u3]
```

in Groovy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using `inject` and `withDefault`:

```
def map = [u2:['g2','g3'], u3:['g1','g2','g3'], u1:['g1','g2']]

assert map.inject([:].withDefault{ [] }) { newMap, k, v -> 
    v.collect { newMap[it] << k }     
    newMap
} == ['g2':['u2', 'u3', 'u1'], 'g3':['u2', 'u3'], 'g1':['u3', 'u1']]
```

Comment: If sorting is required for the values in the new map then append this call to above newly created map `.collectEntries { k, v -> [k, v.sort()] }`